# Submitting a comment form and displaying that comment within a modal window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-post

I have a simple html comment form below that is located in a file that gets loaded within a modal window. What I am attempting to do is allow the user to enter a comment via the comment form and have that comment show up in the "results div"  within the modal window. The problem I'm having though is that whenever I hit the submit button, the modal window closes (when I run this script on its own, without attempting to load it in a modal window, everything works great). Is there a snippet of code I need to enter (either in the code responsible for creating the modal window or in this script) in-order to prevent this from happening? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate  
/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title></title> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required"

        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.post('result.php', $("#myform").serialize(), 
                              function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
<!-- The Name form field -->  
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="name" id="name">

</textarea>  
<br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
<!-- I will output the results from result.php here -->
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you fire up the console, what's the output from result.php? An error (404, 403, &c) would prevent the "success" function from running.

Comment: For what it is worth, here's a working fiddle. The code you've provided works as-is, so I'm assuming that your result.php is triggering a failure rather than a success. (note that I changed the last <div> to </div>, but that's irrelevant): http://jsfiddle.net/QjG4d/

Comment: Add a basic error handler and let us know what you get: $.ajaxSetup({ error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); } });

Comment: Hey I just want to make sure I'm being clear in what the issue is. I have home.php and on that page I have a link that opens a modal window. Within the modal window I load the script above which is named comments.php. When comments.php is run on it's own (without trying to load it in a modal window, everything runs smoothly and I get the expected results within the "results" div. However when comments.php is loaded within the modal window and I hit the submit button, the modal window closes without submitting the form to result.php. If you already understood this I apologize.

Comment: If you want I can also post the code that generates the modal window (home.php).

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more clear. Sorry for the delay. Please provide home.php, though. The issue is not within the code you've posted.